# about the scaling after normalization and transformation in RNA-seq data

Tags: r, rna

When we use count data in RNA-seq analysis, we usually use normalization and sometimes vst, rlog transformation (DESeq2)or log2(CMP+4) transformation (edgeR) to perform K-means clustering. Can we use scaling after normalization and transformation?
Or Should we use scaling only when we just use normalization without transformation?